# How to run ajax in certain time interval in Magento2

Tags: magento2, ajax

I have added ajax to show a text which is fetched from my scope config(The value is given in the store->configuration). In my controller I am getting the value using scope config and used echo in it.
In my ajax function, I am using the url of my controller to print the data in html div tag. I want to make the ajax function running all the time, so that if I change the value the ajax has to update the text automatically without any action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
setTimeout(function(){ callAjaxRequest(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot @simonthesorcerer

Answer (score 0):

"If I change the value" according to this use the onChange jquery function to get it to work. Now if this is coming from store config (I guess not too much data) you can save all values into JS variable using block or helper and use it using the onChange function which will be faster compare to ajax calls.

Comment: If possible I will try this method. Thanks for your suggestion.